# python project import uwsgi how to do unit test?

Tags: python, uwsgi, python-unittest

My Flask app is using `uwsgi spooler` so I `import uwsgi` in the project.But when I run my unit test cases, Then

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "runapp.py", line 55, in <module>
    import topicservice 
  File "/home/workspace/topic.py", line 36, in <module>
    import uwsgi
ImportError: No module named uwsgi
```

I know uwsgi is not a python module, it is a binary server.The app run by uwsgi can access the "uwsgi" module. But is there any way do my unit test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came to the same problem while encountering the RPC function used throughout a project. There is no official way around it, but I can share my solution.

You should extract the desired functionality to a separate class/function that lazy loads the `uwsgi` module. Example for `uwsgi.rpc`:

```
class RPCSender:

def __init__(self, host_address):
    self._host_address = host_address

def send(self, destination, data):
    import uwsgi

    uwsgi.rpc(self._host_address, destination, data)

...

local_rpc_sender = RPCSender('192.168.173.100:3031')
local_rpc_sender.send('myfunc', 'myarg')
```

Now, when you write tests for modules that use `RPCSender`, you should mock out the `send` method. Preferably by using `mock.patch.object`. It's not against any rules of unit testing since there is no point in testing `uwsgi.rpc` - it's a third party library which testing is not our responsibility - we assume that it works as intended.